# Property undefined halfway through Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to compare each object in the two arrays in order to find matches. Currently, I am only comparing one property, but plan to compare two properties when I can get this part working.

I find it odd that it works for the first three items in the array and returns an error on the fourth.  Here is the console output in Chrome:

```
Washington  
Smith  
yes  
Jones  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var self = this;
self.people = [
    { id: '1', name: 'Washington' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Smith' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Jones' },
    { id: '1', name: 'Smith' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Washington' }
];

self.params = [
    {id: '1', name: 'Jones'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Smith'}];

for (var value in self.params) {
    for (var value in self.people) {
        console.log(self.people[value].name);
        if (self.people[value].name == self.params[value].name) {
            console.log('yes');
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the if statement, the code runs without error and prints the "names" in the people array twice as expected. Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for (var value in self.params)` will iterate through keys of array, leading `value` to be `0, 1, length...`. Do you really understand what you are doing with this code?

Comment: Nooooo, don't use `for..in` on arrays!

Comment: Perhaps not. Apologies. I am a novice and am trying to write something that will compare the property values in two different arrays, returning the results. Any suggestions to achieve that goal are very welcome.

Comment: you are getting this error because size of outer array does not match to inner array. so after 2 element 3 element is blank in second array.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I am also getting the same error when I replace the for...in with basic for loops to iterate each through array. It makes one pass through the entire people array and then returns the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (var value in self.params) {
    for (var value1 in self.people) {
        console.log(self.people[value1].name);
        if (self.people[value1].name == self.params[value].name) {
            console.log('yes');
        }
    }
}
```

You are using the same variable for both the loops...

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

You're using twice the variable name "value".

Btw in Javascript the variables aren't scoped at block level (your 2 var declarations in the 2 for), but they're either global or function scoped.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe the next lines can give you a hint:

```
var val,
   value;
for (val in self.params) {
    for (value in self.people) {
        console.log(self.people[value].name);
        if (self.people[value].name == self.params[val].name) {
            console.log('yes');
        }
    }
}
```